# Get method output from a lambda expression in HangFire ContinueJobWith Method

Tags: c#, lambda, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, hangfire

```
var scheduleJobId1 = _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step One"), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(5));
_backgroundJobClient.ContinueJobWith(scheduleJobId1, () => _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step two"), TimeSpan.FromHours(7)), JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState);
_backgroundJobClient.ContinueJobWith(?2?, () => _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step Three"), TimeSpan.FromHours(4)), JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState);
```

I have three stages of consecutive jobs. These steps must be scheduled in sequence.
In the second step, I got the job ID in the first step And using the ContinueJobWith ​​method in HangFire, I set the second step 7 hours after the first step. Now I want to set the third step 4 hours after the second step. To do this, I need the second stage job ID But the second job is defined as lambda , so how do I get its ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var scheduleJobId1 = _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step One"), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(5));
_backgroundJobClient.ContinueWith(scheduleJobId1, () => 
  _backgroundJobClient.ContinueWith(
    _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step two"), TimeSpan.FromHours(7)), () => _backgroundJobClient.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine("Step Three"), TimeSpan.FromHours(4)), JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState), 
    JobContinuationOptions.OnlyOnSucceededState);
```